# Windows iOS simulator [Preview]: unable to install Xamarin iOS app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I need to debug my Xamarin iOS app in [iOS Simulator (for Windows)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/), but am getting an error of fail to install

[image]

I changed my Mac "Full name" as "Account", but am still getting same error.

Comment: You should not use the Full Bame to log in to your mac biuld host, but the short UNIX user name that is the name of your Mac user's home folder, or can be retrieved from the command line with `whoami` when logged in as that Mac user. Do you have XCode and Xamarin installed on your mac build host? You still need the iOS simulators and SDKs installed on the mac build host to use the iOS Simulator Remote for Windows.

Comment: I am doing same as you mention but still getting same error.I am login with short UNIX user name. We have already installed Xcode and Xamarin. We have already installed simulator and sdk also.